# Use of long long int in 2D Array

Tags: c++, c, unsigned-long-long-int

What is the meaning of  "Grid[i][1] = 1LL" in the following code?

```
typedef long long int ll;        
ll Grid[10][10];

for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{  
   if(Grid[i][1] == 0)   
   {  
      Grid[i][1] = 1LL;  
   }  
   else
      break;  
}
```

Comment: LL == long long.

Comment: `typedef long long int ll;` - that's a great way to obfuscate your code. Don't do things like that.